# Why doesn't [1] equals to [1]?

Tags: javascript

in JavaScript:

```
(1 == 1) === true;
(1 === 1) === true;
```

and

```
var a = 1;
var b = [1];
(a == b) === true
```

but

```
([1]==[1]) === false;
```

Why is it so? I have no idea

Answer (score 13):

`[1]` and the other `[1]` are different objects, and object equality is defined as identity. In other words, an object is only equal to itself.

```
> a = [1]
[1]
> b = [1]
[1]
> a == b
false
> b = a
[1]
> a == b
true
```

Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3, step 1.f is what applies here.

Answer (score 6):

Because `[1]` and `[1]` are two instances of the Array object. As such, they are not equal (two objects are equal only if they are the exact same instance).

However, when you compare `1` and `[1]`, there needs to be type juggling involved.

Arrays can be cast to a string, by joining all items with a comma. This results in the string `"1"`.

In turn, `"1"` can be cast to a number, giving `1`. `1 == 1` is clearly true.

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are objects and they are compared by reference rather than value so only the same instances are equal

For example:

```
var array1 = [1];
var array2 = array1;
(array1 == array2) === true;
(array1 == [1]) === false
```

Answer (score 0):

please see here: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)

the `[]` syntax is a literal constructor for Array objects, and objects cannot be compared to others (well they can, with negative result).

Answer (score 0):

Strings and numbers are immutable in JavaScript, so you're literally comparing the content of a certain block in memory with itself when you do something like `"string" === "string"` or `1 === 1`, whereas you're constructing a new Array object each time you use the constructor.

I hope this makes sense.